# How to use SDL2 and SDL_image with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-image

I'm looking for the simplest way to compile a c++ program using **SDL2** and **SDL_image** with cmake.

Here is my best attempt, after hours of searching:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(shooter-cmake2)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(SOURCES
shooter.cpp
classes.cpp
utils.cpp
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2_image REQUIRED sdl2_image)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARY})
```

I get these errors:

```
In function `loadTexture(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, SDL_Renderer*)':
undefined reference to `IMG_LoadTexture'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the function call:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"

SDL_Texture* loadTexture(const std::string &file, SDL_Renderer *ren){
    SDL_Texture *texture = IMG_LoadTexture(ren, file.c_str());
    texture != nullptr or die("LoadTexture");
    return texture;
}
```

Comment: Remember that SDL is a *C* library, and not a C++ library. So using C++ classes like `std::string` as arguments will most likely not work.

Comment: Also, since you're new here on SO, if you have a question regarding build (compiler or linker) errors, please include the *complete* and *unedited* error log in your question, including the code that causes the error (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). In your case please **edit your question** to include the code where you call `IMG_LoadTexture` together with enough context to understand the code (like variable declarations etc.).

Comment: Don't know any cmake specifics, but shouldn't you add `${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}` as well?

Comment: @keltar I tried: same errors. (I edited my post)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think that the following will work, as it finds the libraries on my ubuntu system and the example function you provided can link:

```
project(shooter-cmake2)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/test.cpp)

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)

PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image>=2.0.0)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES})
```

If cmake is executed with --debug-output it outputs:

```
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 
Called from: [2]    /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake
            [1] $USER/stack-overflow/cmake-sdl2-image/CMakeLists.txt
-- checking for one of the modules 'sdl2'
Called from: [1]    $USER/stack-overflow/cmake-sdl2-image/CMakeLists.txt
-- checking for one of the modules 'SDL2_image>=2.0.0'
Called from: [1]    $USER/stack-overflow/cmake-sdl2-image/CMakeLists.txt
```

This made me check the contents of

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/sdl2.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/SDL2_image.pc
```

I noticed that SDL2_image.pc contains 
    Name: SDL2_image
which I assumed should match the third parameter to PKG_SEARCH_MODULE for this library.

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm! Where did you find how to do this? What reference?

Comment: I did not use any reference just what I could read from the source of the module you use and what I know about how .pc files work .. I updated the answer with additional info. :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! But how has `--debug-output` helped you? I'm just trying to understand how you worked it out.

Comment: The debug output told me that pkg was used and that one library configured used one pkg file was working while another was not. That narrows it down.

Comment: Since CMake 3.1, `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD yy)` is preferred over modifying `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: You should definitely improve the answer. ;)

Comment: That was awesome! Thanks!

Comment: In my case the modules name has to be `SDL2_IMAGE` instead of `SDL2IMAGE`.

Comment: Woah, so current Ubuntu 18.04 fails to locate SDL2_image with `find_package`, but *this* works!? I'm really trying (this time) not to use explicit paths, and found that on some systems I have to use `find_package` in "config" mode - but now this? I read then that `FindPkgConfig` is somehow "external" to CMake...but if it does find the elusive SDL2_image, maybe it will find all my other libraries too...is this the future or the past...one ring to rule them all...it'll only take a few more hours to check...

Answer (score 11):

There are two blog posts about this here:

[Using SDL2 with CMake](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake/)

[Using SDL2_image with CMake](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/07/04/using-sdl2-image-with-cmake/)

Basically you need a `FindSDL2.cmake` and `FindSDL2_image.cmake` module. They can be based of the ones that work for SDL 1.2 which are included in CMake already. Using these Find modules will also work on Windows.

If you are on Linux and only need SDL2 you don't even need the `FindSDL2.cmake` as the following already works:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(SDL2Test)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(SDL2Test Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SDL2Test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: How does this work on Linux? (I have seen that it does.) Is there a FindSDL2.cmake installed with CMake on Linux?

Comment: The module list for current CMake (v3.12) [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake-modules.7.html) doesn't appear to include SDL2 support, so how does this work?

Comment: SDL2 under linux includes a CMake config file. That way it works without a FindSDL2 module.

Comment: It works on mac with brew too

Answer (score 6):

I was having trouble with these answers, I think cmake changed the way to import targets. Following @trenki blog post I needed to change my CMakeLists.txt to:

```
project(SDL2Test)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS SDL2::SDL2)
add_executable(SDL2Test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SDL2Test SDL2::SDL2)
```

Currently this works out of the box on Arch Linux.

Comment: I also saw some similar double colon stuff, but couldn't get it to work with SDL2_image. It all depends on whether different flavours of ad-hoc "find" configuration files are present on your system. CMake does demand your patience. Can we not all just agree to put our files in the same place :)

Answer (score 5):

I introduced a modern and portable approach for linking to the SDL2, SDL2_image. These [SDL2 CMake modules](https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules) let you build an SDL2 & SDL2_image project as follows :

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/sdl2)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2::Main SDL2::Image)
```

You should just clone the repo in your project:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules cmake/sdl2
```

**Note:** If CMake didn't find the SDL2/SDL2_image libraries (in Windows), we can specify the CMake options `SDL2_PATH` and `SDL2_IMAGE_PATH` as follows:

```sh
cmake .. -DSDL2_PATH="/path/to/sdl2" -DSDL2_IMAGE_PATH="/path/to/sdl2-image"
```

It supports also other related libraries : SDL2_ttf, SDL2_net, SDL2_mixer and SDL2_gfx. For more details, please read the [README.md](https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules) file.

You can find a list of examples/samples and projects that uses these modules here : https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl-samples-and-projects

Answer (score 4):

Since 2.6 version, SDL2_image installation is shipped with CMake config script `SDL2_imageConfig.cmake`/`SDL2_image-config.cmake`.

So `find_package(SDL2_image)` works without any additional `FindSDL2_image.cmake` module, and creates IMPORTED target `SDL2_image::SDL2_image`:

```
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(<executable-target> SDL2_image::SDL2_image)
```

---

Note, that variables like `SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES` or `SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS` are NOT set in this case, so using them is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands works fine for me:

```
set(SDL_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/include/SDL2")
set(SDL_LIBRARY "SDL2")
include(FindSDL)  

if(SDL_FOUND)  
  message(STATUS "SDL FOUND")
endif()
```