# Cmake linking external libraries

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake

How to link external libraries with cmake?
i want to include header files (Liblaries/include) 
and link .lib files(Liblaries/lib) + opengl lib.

[image]

Comment: I'm new to CMake, but I think you're looking for something like `target_link_libraries(Game ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/glew32s.lib ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/glfw3.lib)` and `target_include_directories(Game ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)`. It appears that your `CMakeLists.txt` file exists in `Liblaries` directory already, so you shouldn't need `Liblaries` in your paths for the target commands.

Comment: In the future, you should be aware that it's usually more helpful to post the code that isn't working and also explain what you've tried already that hasn't worked. The image is useful for showing your project's directory structure, but that's all.

Answer (score 1):

```
ADD_LIBRARY(LibsModule 
        file1.cpp
        file2.cpp
    )
```

then add them to a module call `LibsModule`

```
target_link_libraries(LibsModule -lpthread)
```

Please refer to this post:
[Adding Libraries with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598323/how-to-properly-link-libraries-with-cmake)

As an advice please use the "Similar Question Asked" before posting to avoid getting downvoted or being closed as duplicate.
Cheer