# how to link custom static libraries in cmakelist

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a c++ project with clion,using capstone,and I dont know to much cmake syntax for sure
there is my project tree
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYbHB.png)

there is a function (called a()) used in main.cpp, declared in cstool.h and implemented in cstool.cpp

and there are function print_insn_detail_arm(),print_insn_detail_arm64(),print_insn_detail_x86() used in a(),

```
print_insn_detail_arm() implemented in cstool_arm.c

print_insn_detail_arm64() implemented in cstool_arm64.c

print_insn_detail_x86() implemented in cstool_x86.c
no header files for the three .c files
```

but there error when building

I think that the libcstool_arch.a didnot be linked to the project, but I dont know how to write correct sentence.

not sure if the header files are necessary for the three .c file

I think maybe there are some errors or imperfect thinking in cmake sentence sequence and other aspects, wishing for guidance and advices as a beginner

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we dislike **images** which just contain a **code** or/and an **error message**. Instead we expect these things to be included into the question post as **text**. Please, read [ask] and update your question accordingly.

Comment: CMake looks OK to me. Since you use those functions without a header file, I assume you do some extern / forward declaration of these functions? Maybe the argument types don't match with what is expected?

Comment: Hello! You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598323/how-to-properly-link-libraries-with-cmake?rq=1) post for linking static library with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right on the CMake front, but you did not take C++ name mangling into account.
Concretely, C++ and C disagree on the symbol name that corresponds to `print_insn_detail_arm()`:

```
$ nm from_c.o
U _print_insn_detail_arm
$ nm from_cpp.o
U __Z21print_insn_detail_armv
```

In order to fix this, you need to tell the C++ compiler to expect the non-mangled forms of these function names when you declare them:

```
extern "C" {
void print_insn_detail_arm();
}
```

Finally, it is worth putting this in a header file for both C++ and C so you get nice compile-time errors if you ever change the interface. For that, you need to hide the `extern` bit from the C compiler, as it does not understand that:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void print_insn_detail_arm();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

For more background information, see [Combining C++ and C - how does #ifdef __cplusplus work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789340/combining-c-and-c-how-does-ifdef-cplusplus-work)

Comment: thanks a lot, I didnot notice there is c++ call c function problem. That's an important minor point