# How to correctly link SFML staticly? (Clion, CMake, Windows 10 x64)

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, undefined-reference

I'm linking SFML **staticly**, with CMake, and I'm getting undefined reference errors to all SFML classes or methods.
CmakeLists.txt (**SFML is in the same directory, and is x64**):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(YeOldFlapper)

add_definitions(-DSFML_STATIC)

set(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR "SFML/include")
set(SFML_LIB_DIR "SFML/lib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${SFML_LIB_DIR})


add_executable(YeOldFlapper main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(YeOldFlapper sfml-graphics-s sfml-window-s sfml-system-s)
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

namespace SFML = sf;

int main() {
    SFML::RenderWindow window(SFML::VideoMode(500, 500), "SFML WORKS!!!");

    while(window.isOpen()){
        SFML::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){
            switch (event.type) {
                case SFML::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.display();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I well linked, but i'g getting undefined references.

Comment: Starting from SFML 2.2, when static linking, you will have to link all of SFML's dependencies to your project as well. This means that if you are linking sfml-window-s.lib or sfml-window-s-d.lib for example, you will also have to link opengl32.lib, winmm.lib and gdi32.lib.

Comment: Well I changed the CmakeLists.txt target_link_libraries to ```target_link_libraries(YeOldFlapper opengl32 winmm gdi32 sfml-graphics-s sfml-window-s sfml-system-s)```
but is is still throwing the same errors

Comment: Can you post the errors? Based on [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39600062/7034621) I would assume you're supposed to pass `-lsfml-graphics-s` instead of `sfml-graphics-s`.

Comment: Basically this for all sfml calls:
```C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Mokykla/CLionProjects/SFML/Projects/YeOldFlapper/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'```

Comment: Are you linking binaries compiled for MinGW? Is the extension `.a` and not `.lib`? MinGW binaries should have a `.a` extension for the static libraries. msvc should have `.lib`

Comment: Ok so I switched the VisualStudio sfml for mingw, and it compiles BUT now something called libgcc_s_seh-1.dll wasn't found

Comment: That dll should be in your MinGW bin folder. If it's not your SFML libraries are not compatible with your current compiler. My advice is to avoid this problem entirely and use msys2 to install MinGW and SFML using pacman from the mingw64 terminal.  The VSCode documentation tells you to use msys2 to install MinGW anyways: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Answer (score 0):

The OP discovered that the link issue seen was due to him mixing up which libraries he thought he was linking with. He thought he was linking with MING32 SFML as but found he'd attempted to link with VC SFML.

Docs for SFML and CMake can be found here: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php