# Clion Cmake & SDL2

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2, clion

I want to use Clion with SDL2 and after lot of tests, I already have an error.

there is my CmakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(sdl2-test)

#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lmingw32")
#set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(sdl2-test ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(sdl2-test SDL2main SDL2)
```

my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "include/SDL2/SDL.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1){
        cout << "Something went wrong! " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    }

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_Demo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                      1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if(window == nullptr){
        cout << "Something also went wrong here" << endl;
    }

    SDL_Delay(2000);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;

}
```

but when I build my project cmake Obviously Cmake work find but I haave some error :

```
C:\Users\paulp\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\172.4343.16    \bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\paulp\CLionProjects\sdl2-test\cmake-    build-debug --target sdl2-test -- -j 4
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sdl2-test.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable sdl2-test.exe
CMakeFiles\sdl2-test.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `SDL_main':
C:/Users/paulp/CLionProjects/sdl2-test/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:/Users/paulp/CLionProjects/sdl2-test/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:/Users/paulp/CLionProjects/sdl2-test/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:/Users/paulp/CLionProjects/sdl2-test/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
C:/Users/paulp/CLionProjects/sdl2-test/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\sdl2-test.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'sdl2-test.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [sdl2-test.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sdl2-test.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sdl2-test.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sdl2-test.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sdl2-test.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [sdl2-test] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'sdl2-test' failed
```

any idea how to fix ?

Comment: I guess you downloaded the right mingw devel version

Comment: I guess, I download SDL2-devel-2.0.6-mingw.tar.gz and I use mingw 5.0

Answer (score 0):

The linking of your application has failed because the linker does not know the location of the sdl2-lib.

You need to search for the SDL2-libraries as well in your cmake-file and add the locations to your makefile:

```
find_file(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR NAME SDL.h HINTS SDL2)
find_library(SDL2_LIBRARY NAME SDL2)
add_executable(ChickenShooter main.cpp)
target_include_directories(ChickenShooter ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(ChickenShooter ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

You can look into this post as well: [How to dins SDL2 via cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395833/using-sdl2-with-cmake)

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (target_include_directories):
  target_include_directories called with invalid arguments

Comment: How I can add location on my makefile ?

Comment: Done in my example by target_include_directories(ChickenShooter ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(ChickenShooter ${SDL2_LIBRARY})