# Clion (cmake) won't link the libraries

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, sdl-2, clion

I'm having a problem when trying to link **SDL2** and **GL** libraries to Clion (cmake). Despite changing the cmakelists.txt and adding the target-link-libraries() function. So the cmake file looked like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(OpenGL1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

target_link_libraries(OpenGL1 SDL2 GL)

add_executable(OpenGL1 main.cpp Display1.cpp Display1.h)
```

But with no luck. Clion would not link the libraries with errors such as undifined refference to functions of the libraries.

Then a friend suggested it that I would wite that into cmakelists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(OpenGL1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lGL -lSDL2 -lOpenGL")


add_executable(OpenGL1 main.cpp Display1.cpp Display1.h)
```

And it kinda worked... But it would not find the *-lOpenGL*.
Last but not least, my project will not compile with the traditional way in the terminal with g++. And it will compile fine with one .cpp file.
My project consists of 2 cpp files and a header file. Like that:

- main.cpp
- Display1.cpp
- Display.h

And code of the files is the following:

1. main.cpp

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "Display.h"

   using namespace std;

   int main() {
       Display d1(800,600,"Hello");

       while (!d1.m_isClosed()){
           d1.Clear(0.0f, 0.15f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
           d1.Update();
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Display1.cpp

   ```
   #include "Display.h"
   #include <GL/glew.h>

   using namespace std;

   Display::Display(int width, int height, const string title) {
       SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
       SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE,8);
       SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE,8);
       SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE,8);
       SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE,8);
       SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE,32);
       SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER,1);

       m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(),SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,width,height,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
       m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);

       GLenum status = glewInit();
       if (status != GLEW_OK)
           cerr << "Glew failed!" << endl;

       isClosed = false;
   }

   Display::~Display() {
       SDL_GL_DeleteContext(m_glContext);
       SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
       SDL_Quit();
   }

   void Display::Clear(float r, float g, float b, float a) {
       glClearColor(r,g,b,a);
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   }

   bool Display::m_isClosed() {
       return isClosed;
   }

   void Display::Update() {
       SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);

       SDL_Event e;
       while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
           if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
               isClosed = true;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Display1.h

   ```
    #ifndef OPENGL_DISPLAY_H
    #define OPENGL_DISPLAY_H

    #include <iostream>
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>

    using namespace std;


    class Display {
     SDL_Window* m_window;
     SDL_GLContext m_glContext;
     bool isClosed;
    public:
      Display(int width, int height, string title);
      virtual ~Display();
      void Update();
      bool m_isClosed();
      void Clear(float r, float g, float b, float a);
   };


   #endif //OPENGL_DISPLAY_H
   ```

Now, i know that others have asked the same, but nothing could help me so that's why I'm asking. I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 (64-bit). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try using the following FindSDL2 cmake script to find the dependencies for you. An example of linking them to your program can be found in the README: https://github.com/tcbrindle/sdl2-cmake-scripts. You can use the builtin findOpenGL to do the same thing for OpenGL: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenGL.html

Comment: Do you get some cmake errors? E.g. `target_link_libraries` should come after `add_executable`. In your order it's wrong.

Comment: You need to find the libraries. Therefor you can use `find_package`, e.g. `find_package(OpenGL)`. Then you need to add the include directories and link the libraries with `include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})` resp. `target_link_libraries(OpenGL1 ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SDL2 with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395833/using-sdl2-with-cmake)

Comment: @ThomasSablik That's correct. Wrote it wrong, but I had the correct order despite writing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix your CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(OpenGL1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/include/SDL2)
set(SDL2_LIBRARIES /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.so)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(OpenGL1 main.cpp Display1.cpp Display1.h)

target_link_libraries(OpenGL1 ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

First find the OpenGL files with `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)`. Then set the paths for SDL2. Set the include directories for your target (OpenGL1). Add your target. Link libraries to your target.

A better way to use SDL2 is to use [FindSDL2.cmake](https://github.com/brendan-w/collector/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake) and add `find_package(SDL2)` to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(OpenGL1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(OpenGL1 main.cpp Display1.cpp Display1.h)

target_link_libraries(OpenGL1 ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

SDL2 installs its own cmake configuration file called sdl2-config.cmake, so you don't need to download it from github.

Comment: Thanks! But got this error: c++: error: $(SDL2_LIBRARY): Δεν υπάρχει τέτοιο αρχείο ή κατάλογος (no such file or directory in greek.)

Comment: You have to install SDL2 and set the paths yourself. You can search with `find /usr -name libSDL2.so`. On my Ubuntu it is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.so`. When you use FindSDL2.cmake, the script will configure the pass for you.

Comment: I made some steps. I didn't play with "FindSDL2.cmake", but set the paths for the sdl2, opengl directories, I used the find_library function and provided the exact path for both libraries and then linked them but still got the error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOPENGL". In which I don't have access.

Comment: Are you sure, that OpenGL is installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, I checked and everything is installed.

Comment: Can you post your CMakeLists.txt. Do you use `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)`? Did you remove `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lGL -lSDL2 -lOpenGL")`?

Comment: My current version of cmakelists is: 

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(OpenGL1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/SDL2)
set(OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/GL)
set(SDL2_LIBRARY /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.so)
set(OPENGL_LIBRARY /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/compiz/libopengl.so)${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

link_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(OpenGL1 main.cpp Display1.cpp Display1.h)
target_link_libraries(OpenGL1 SDL2_LIBRARY OPENGL_LIBRARY)

Comment: Now you are mixing two methods. That can't work. Clear your CMakeLists.txt and copy my second CMakeLists.txt. It should work. You have syntax errors and logical errors in your configuration.

Comment: Ok, I used yours, but got error "undefined reference to `glewInit'".

Comment: Solved it! Had to include GLEW_LIBRARIES.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Fixed it in my answer.