# How to link SDL2 in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I'm trying to use sdl on ubuntu. According to this instruction(https://gist.github.com/BoredBored/3187339a99f7786c25075d4d9c80fad5) i installed sdl2, sdl image and sdl mixer. Now I have to link them while building. Example how should I do it below.

```
g++ myProgram.cpp -o myProgram `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
```

I'm using Cmake and I have no idea how to link them...

Below it's code done just for testing sdl working or not.

```
//MAIN
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

int main(int argc, char*args[])
{
 SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
}
```

CMakeList below

```
# Set the minimum version of CMake that can be used
# To find the cmake version run
# $ cmake --version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Set the project name
project (sdl)

# Create a sources variable with a link to all cpp files to compile
set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
)

# Add an executable with the above sources
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

# Set the directories that should be included in the build command for this target
# when running g++ these will be included as -I/directory/path/
target_include_directories(sdl
    PRIVATE 
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
)
```

How can I link them in Cmake? Thanks for your time.

Comment: [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using SDL2 with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395833/using-sdl2-with-cmake)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To link a library (shared/static) in **cmake** you can use the [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command:

```
target_link_libraries(<target> ... <item>... ...)
```

According to the documentation:

> `<target>` must have been created by a command such as `add_executable()` or `add_library()`

So first of all we need to find the SDL library, for that we will use the command:

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
```

to make it's include directories available to you, use the command:

```
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

And finally to link SDL2, you need to do:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

or **alternatively**:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2)
```

`PRIVATE`, means that `${PROJECT_NAME}` uses `SDL2` in its implementation, but `SDL2` is not used in any part of `${PROJECT_NAME}`'s public API. [More here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-May/063400.html)

Here `${PROJECT_NAME}` is the `<target>`, and all the rest that follow are names of libraries.

#### Final Result

```
# Set the minimum version of CMake that can be used
# To find the cmake version run
# $ cmake --version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Set the project name
project (sdl)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

# Create a sources variable with a link to all cpp files to compile
set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
)

# Add an executable with the above sources
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(sdl ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

# Set the directories that should be included in the build command for this target
include_directories(SDL2Test ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Refs:

1. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command
2. https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-May/063400.html

Comment: Note that `sdl2-config.cmake` also defines the `SDL2::SDL2` and `SDL2::SDL2-static` IMPORTED targets. Using these with `target_link_libraries` automatically sets up the include directories _AND_ linker flags.

Comment: See [it's time to do CMake right](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/) as for why IMPORTED targets are preferred over the variables.

Comment: After  changing  CMakeList to yours somehow there is still problem while building.```fatal error: SDL2/SDL_ttf.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>```

Comment: @LuQ232 are you sure you have SDL2 installed and can find it in `/usr/include/...`

Comment: @Botje would exported target i.e., `SDL2::SDL2` work with old version of cmake such as 3.5 in this case?

Comment: @Waqar yeah. I had to install one more lib. My mistake! NOW IT WORKS FINE! Best answear going to you!

Comment: @Waqar CMake 3.0 (released 2014) already knew about IMPORTED targets, and there is little reason to delay CMake upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT*** added the full CMAKE

```
# Set the minimum version of CMake that can be used
# To find the cmake version run
# $ cmake --version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Set the project name
project (sdl)

# Create a sources variable with a link to all cpp files to compile
set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
)

 target_include_directories(sdl
        PRIVATE 
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
    )

# Add an executable with the above sources

link_directories(path_to_lib)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})


# Set the directories that should be included in the build command for this target
# when running g++ these will be included as -I/directory/path/


 target_link_libraries((${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2 SDL2_mixer SDL2_image SDL2_ttf)
```

Comment: After this line now I have error like this:```CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "lSDL2" which is not built by this
  project.```

Comment: add link_directories(path_to_lib)

Comment: Your `target_link_libraries` has an extra `l` for all the libraries.