# How can I link a library with SDL2 in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm planning on writing a small 2D game engine in C++, using SDL2 for rendering. I want to write a wrapper library for SDL2 to make it easier to use for myself. How can I link this library with SDL2 using CMake?

Comment: I believe its pretty much the same as any library when using CMake. Here is an example: [https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake/](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake/)

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395833/using-sdl2-with-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395833/using-sdl2-with-cmake)

Answer (score 1):

So you want your application to link against the wrapper library like this:

```
Application  -->  Wrapper lib  -->  Actual lib
```

The steps are:

#### 1. Locate the actual library

Try the simpliest way to find an installed library on your system:

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
```

That should be enough for newer cmake releases. For older versions - see linked questions about how to locate SDL2 with CMake.

#### 2. Create a pseudo-target for that library

The first step left you with bare cmake variables `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `SDL2_LIBRARIES`. Though it's possible to use them as is, it would be much more convenient to combine them in a single target, and use that target through the rest of your CMakeLists.txt file. Creating an INTERFACE target for an external library is somewhat easier than creating an IMPORTED target, so:

```
add_library               (external.sdl2 INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(external.sdl2 INTERFACE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries     (external.sdl2 INTERFACE ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Now, every time you link *anything* againts the target `external.sdl2`, both include directories and the actual library will be pulled in automatically.

#### 3. Define the target for your wrapper library

```
add_library(my_wrapper STATIC
    my_wrapper.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(my_wrapper
    external.sdl2
)
```

Note: you don't need explicit `include_directories` any more.

#### 4. Define the target for your main executable

```
add_executable(my_game
    my_game.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(my_game
    my_wrapper
)
```

Likewise, you don't have to mention SDL2 in target libraries, not include directories; they will be added implicitly because `my_wrapper` target uses it.

P.S. Since this is a C++ project, why not use SDL2PP, the C++ wrapper on SDL2?