# How do I check for SDL2_ttf in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I am currently writing an SDL2 program with the SDL2-ttf library and wanted to add a check for it in CMakeLists.txt. How do I do that?

I am using CMake 3.1.

Comment: I tweaked your title to [remove a tag from it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) and include a more specific qualifier.

Comment: did you ever find a working answer for this?   I'm pretty sure arved's answer below doesn't work for SDL2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindSDL_ttf.cmake is part of cmake 3.x just use

```
find_package(SDL_ttf REQUIRED)
```

Comment: My understanding is that this doesn't work for SDL2 (as asked in the question), only original SDL.   I was told this on freenode #cmake and it also doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you checked this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850472/how-to-use-sdl2-and-sdl-image-with-cmake

Answer (score 8):

The FindSDL_ttf doesn't work with SDL2, so you'll have to use a third party option.

I've used this and it works:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deraen/ohj2710/master/cmake_modules/FindSDL2TTF.cmake

Just put it in a directory included by `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /path/to/file)`

and then use it `find_package(SDL2TTF)`

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work... I have added `set(cmake_module_path /home/user/project)`, the above linked file I saved in the location `/home/user/project`, then I also added `find_package(SDL2TTF REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(projectname ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARIES})` to my `CMakeLists.txt`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Fixed: Should be `SDL2TTF_LIBRARY`

Comment: Yes, here's what I have:     target_link_libraries(my_target  ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARY})