# TTF_Init undefined reference

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I am currently having a problem using the SDL2 TTF module, I installed the dev files with sudo apt-get, and am using CMake

Here is my code:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"

int main(){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    TTF_Init();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my CMakeLists.txt file.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (MyProject)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-variable -std=c++14")
set (source_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/")

file (GLOB source_files "${source_dir}/*.cpp")

add_executable (MyProject ${source_files})

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)

PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image>=2.0.0)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf>=2.0.0)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARIES})
```

and this is the output

```
----------Building project:[ MyProject - Debug ]----------
Scanning dependencies of target MyProject
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable MyProject
CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/bram/Dev/c++/sdl/MyProject/src/main.cpp:68: undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/build.make:120: recipe for target 'MyProject' failed
make[2]: *** [MyProject] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Comment: I supose it depends on what your `FindSDL2ttf.cmake` sets. Find this file and look what it does. Is it yours or comes with your distro's SDL2_ttf package? If so, which one is it?

Comment: Okay, after not being able to find the file you meant I created one and got the contents from  I just figured it out by using this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056249/how-do-i-check-for-sdl2-ttf-in-cmakelists-txt/34269603#34269603. Thanks man!