# CMake could not find SDL2

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

I want to add [this library](https://github.com/libSDL2pp/libSDL2pp/) to my project. However, it does not come with pre-compiled files. It asks me to build the library myself with `cmake`, which I am not familiar with. One of its dependencies is SDL2. So I download the sdl2 development libraries folder. In cmake, I click configure and choose the generator. After a couple of seconds processing, a window pops up showing the error: `Error in configuration process project files may be invalid`

And this is what the log screen shows:

> The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
>  The CXX
> compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.40629.0
>  Check for working C
> compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
>  Check for working C compiler
> using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
>  Detecting C compiler ABI
> info
>  Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>  Check for working
> CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
>  Check for working CXX
> compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
>  Detecting CXX
> compiler ABI info
>  Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> Detecting CXX compile features
>  Detecting CXX compile features -
> done
>  CMake Error at C:/Program Files
> (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148
> (message):   Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR
> SDL2_LIBRARY)
>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
> C:/Program Files
> (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388
> (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)   cmake/FindSDL2.cmake:18
> (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)   CMakeLists.txt:30 (FIND_PACKAGE)
>
> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>  See also "E:/game
> dev/libraries/libSDL2pp-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Could anyone tell me what to do? I am not sure that I am doing the right thing.

Comment: You need to have SDL2 installed (you did) and you have to tell CMake where to look for it. Just edit the variables mentioned in the output (SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR SDL2_LIBRARY).

Comment: What do you mean by editting the variables? Can you explain a little more detail?

Comment: With the CMake-Gui you get a list of variables. Or edit CMakeCache.txt inside your build directory.

Comment: You may modify the SDL 1.2 modules... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850472/how-to-use-sdl2-and-sdl-image-with-cmake/44900762#44900762

Answer (score -1):

cmake doesn't come with a module for finding sdl2 by default. That's most likely the reason why you provided your own in cmake/FindSDL2.cmake. As you are on windows, it is most likely that you have to set an environment variable to point to the sdl2 installation directory (but this is really something that depends on the FindSDL2.cmake that you use).