# cmake: leading or trailing whitespace (policy CMP0004)

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

I am following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850472/how-to-use-sdl2-and-sdl-image-with-cmake). However my `cmake` faces with error:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_executable):
  Target "main" links to item "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2 " which has
  leading or trailing whitespace.  This is now an error according to policy
  CMP0004.


-- Generating done
```

What is wrong with the `cmake` list?

I do not think the slight `cmake` version difference leads to such an error.

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project (main)

add_executable(main
    main.cpp
)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(main ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

.

```
// main.cpp

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

The content of 
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SDL2/sdl2-config.cmake`

is

```
# sdl2 cmake project-config input for ./configure scripts

set(prefix "/usr") 
set(exec_prefix "${prefix}")
set(libdir "${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
set(SDL2_PREFIX "/usr")
set(SDL2_EXEC_PREFIX "/usr")
set(SDL2_LIBDIR "${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${prefix}/include/SDL2")
set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "-L${SDL2_LIBDIR}  -lSDL2 ")
```

Comment: This looks like a problem in the SDL2-supplied package config file (but I don't use SDL2, so I can't comment more).

Comment: There is should be `sdl2-config.cmake` file shipped with your SDL2 installation (it could be part of `libsdl2-dev` package or so). Show us content of this file. If it looks like this one: https://github.com/xerpi/SDL-Vita/blob/master/sdl2-config.cmake.in (content of *SD2_LIBRARIES* variable is enclosed into double quotes), then the error understandable. Fast fix could be removing these double quotes.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, updated.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, it is interesting. I converted the last line to `set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "-L${SDL2_LIBDIR}  -lSDL2")` and now everything is fine. Thank you very much. I just wonder, why this problem has happened. Is it a bug in `CMake` or `SDL2`?

Comment: It is definitely problem with SDL2 config file.

Comment: You should add that  as the answer, so thankful I found this so fast. Had to google the location too: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SDL2/sdl2-config.cmake. Simply removing that last space fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to edit the `sdl2-config.cmake` file.

You can find this file via command:

```
apt-file search sdl2-config
```

In Ubuntu `Ubuntu 16.04` it is located at

```
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SDL2/sdl2-config.cmake
```

In the source file,

```
# sdl2 cmake project-config input for ./configure scripts

set(prefix "/usr") 
set(exec_prefix "${prefix}")
set(libdir "${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
set(SDL2_PREFIX "/usr")
set(SDL2_EXEC_PREFIX "/usr")
set(SDL2_LIBDIR "${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${prefix}/include/SDL2")
set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "-L${SDL2_LIBDIR}  -lSDL2 ")   <---- here
```

In the last line, there is an extra space which should be removed

```
BEFORE:    set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "-L${SDL2_LIBDIR}  -lSDL2 ")
AFTER :    set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "-L${SDL2_LIBDIR}  -lSDL2")
```

Then, the problem fixed for me.

Answer (score 12):

[ar2015's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48857625/4910684) is right, but its unnecessary to modify `sdl2-config.cmake`.

Just strip the trailing space before `target_link_libraries`:

```
string(STRIP ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} SDL2_LIBRARIES)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: i never like monkeypatching. this is the best answer, but begs the question, why is this bug still around?