# CMake is finding SDL but when running make on the generated makefile I get a "SDL2/SDL.h file not found error"

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, sdl, sdl-2

This is my `CMakeFIle.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project (chippotto)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(chippotto ${SOURCES})

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(chippotto PUBLIC "./include" ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(chippotto ${SDL2_LINK_LIBRARY})
target_compile_options(chippotto PUBLIC ${SDL2_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```

I tried to include SDL as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395833/using-sdl2-with-cmake) other StackOverflow answers ([also checked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850472/how-to-use-sdl2-and-sdl-image-with-cmake)).

This is the output I get:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking for module 'sdl2'
--   Found sdl2, version 2.0.12
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/ninazzo/repos/chippotto/build
```

and as it can be seen from the 4th-to-last line, SDL is found.

If then I try to run `make` in order to build the program, I get the following error:

```
/Users/ninazzo/repos/chippotto/./include/interpreterio.hpp:2:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

and if I try to look for the word "SDL" in the generated makefile I find zero occurrences.

**How can I make my program compile?**

I could throw away `CMake` and use a makefile with `pkg-config` but I was looking for a more portable solution and I'd like to make it work with CMake.

```
I replaced `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR` with `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS` as suggested in the comment section but the problem still remains.
```

Comment: As additional infos, I'm on MacOS running CMake 3.18.2

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS` not `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR`

Comment: I had already tried both ways, but the problem still remains

Comment: Shouldn't you have the headers in `add_executable`?

Comment: Have you tried printing out `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS`? Why are you doing both `pkg_check_modules` and `find_package` for sdl?

Comment: What is the path to SDL.h on your system? What is the value of SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR that CMake found? Chances are, you need to `#include <SDL h>` rather than the old-style path with a slash.